# Deploying the same spring boot kafka streams application sometime works and sometimes it returns HostInfo{host='unavailable', port=-1}

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying out kafka streams interactive queries using spring cloud stream.

1. I deploy the docker image to kubernetes and it works fine.
2. Then I make a change like adding a test and deploy a new image and suddenly it stops working because the host info is no longer available.
   HostInfo{host='unavailable', port=-1}
3. If I redeploy the image from step 1 again, then it starts working again

From looking at the Spring code this occurs in StreamsMetadataState.getMetadataWithKey() if the cluster metadata is empty. The Javadocs suggest that it's due to "if streams is (re-)initializing".

**I can't seem to find an answer as to what one is meant to do in such a situation, and why deploying certain versions of my app work fine and others with simple non logic changes don't**.

I am aggregating data coming from my kafka topic into a persistent window store with a window and retention of 3 days.

Then I am taking the key I created the aggregate with and am making the following call:

```
final HostInfo hostInfo = interactiveQueryService.getHostInfo(STATE_STORE_NAME, key, new StringSerializer());
```

This call sometimes works and return the host and port and other times when it doesn't work returns HostInfo{host='unavailable', port=-1}

My application properties are:

```
spring:
  application.name: my-app-name
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: my-topic
      kafka.streams.binder:
        configuration:
          application.server: ${POD_IP}:${server.port}
          default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
          default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$BytesSerde
  kafka:
    streams:
      application-id: my-app-id
      client-id: my-app-client-id
      replication-factor: 3
      properties:
        num.stream.threads: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Interactive queries are only available if Kafka Streams is in `RUNNING` state (cf `KafkaStreams#state()`). During a rebalance, ie, when a client joins or leave the consumer group and tasks are re-assigned, Interactive Queries are "locked down".

After a rebalance, you need to rediscover state stores (because they might have moved to another instance). Hence, if the metatdata is not available, you can just retry until the rebalance finished.

Check out the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

There is also a demo app on GitHub: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Last, there is a blog post about Interactive Queries: https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I resolved the issue by using brute force as a fallback when the streams metadata is unavailable. The fallback simply iterates over my running pods and calls an endpoint which  checks if the key exists in that instances queryable store, and if it does then it returns the value.

Comment: Instead of brute-force, it might be better to use `KafkaStreams#allMetadata()` (an related methods) and configuration `StreamsConfig#APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG`.